# Uninstall XCode in Lion

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

I just installed Xcode from the installation CD/DCD for my iMac and I don't know where it was installed but it is not in the `/Applications/Developer` folder. Can someone please let me know how I can uninstall this and try to install again as it does not seem to be in the right place. I am trying to install jpeglib and it says xcode is not installed.

Thank you for any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal window and type:Don't modify,type below line exactly.

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: `sudo: /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

This might answer your question:

Maurizio Zilli:

"In new Xcode 4 and Lion You can install and uninstall from Preferences : downloads : components

If You want to uninstall completely XCode go to launchpad and push Xcode icon for two seconds, so click on the upper left checkbox."

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3784638?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be in /Developer/Applications folder?

Comment: Yeah I thought so but I search for that folder and it says it can't be found.

Comment: @pertrai1 you can probably just search all files for the file name "Uninstall" and look for one that has something to do with Xcode, or just find where it was installed in the finder.

Answer (score 0):

It should be installed to `/Developer`. Also, did you install the Unix tools when installing Xcode? The compilation/installation of jpeglib is probably looking for those.

Comment: No I did not. And there is no /Developer folder even though when I search I can find xcode and open it. If I put the CD back in will can I fix this issue? If not, how do I uninstall the damn thing and install it correctly again?

Comment: It's possible it's under another directory, but that shouldn't matter. You do have to install the Unix subsystem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try `open /Applications/Install\ Xcode.app`—it won't remove XCode (it's not installed yet), but will properly finish the installation.

Comment: That is what is screwed up. I get this back:

Comment: did not finish: -bash: /Applications/Install: no such file or directory

Comment: Backslash is essential. Or, you can just use Finder and open the Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar problem. I installed xcode 4 and it installed in `/Applications`, not `/Developer/Applications` like 3.2.